# Find coordinates on circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am having some issues on how to find the coordinate on a circle.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb3n5.jpg)

For example I have the below part of a circle where I know :

1) the **chord d**

2) the **height h**

Based on those 2 I can calculate the radius of the circle with this formula:

$$R=(d^2+4h^2)/(8h)$$

Now I want given any X coordinate to calculate the Y coordinate so that I get the point on the circles circumference

For example if **c=d/2** what is the height **h'** ?

Any idea how may I do this, any idea ?
Thanks in advance. 
Also I know that I have some questions closed but i wasn't able to answer them, so I'm sorry.

Comment: Better use Google before mistagging your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the circle in your setup is

$$\left(x-\frac d2\right)^2+(y+R-h)^2=R^2$$

So, given $x=c$, the corresponding $h’=y$ is

$$h’= \sqrt{ R^2-\left(c-\frac d2\right)^2}-(R-h)$$

where,

$$R=\frac{d^2+4h^2}{8h}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let consider the equation for the circle centered at the origin

$$X^2+Y^2=R^2 \implies Y=\sqrt{R^2-X^2}$$

and then consider a change in coordinates

- $Y=y+(R-h)$
- $X=x-\frac d2$